# asp.net calling a method from front end

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a method in my back end that i would like to call from my front end, but can't seem to get it working. here is my code:

```
<% foreach(string item in Plants){ %>

    <li>
        <span class="folder">
            <asp:label ID="lblPlantName" runat="server" Text='<% GetPlantName(item) %>'></asp:label>
        </span>
    </li>

<%} %>
```

the getplantName method should return a string and fill the text in. But this is not getting called for some reason.

Anyone have any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: You may want to clarify your terminology.  By "front end" and "back end" I think you mean "aspx" and "code behind", respectively, but without the context I would usually interpret "front end" and "back end" to be interpreted as "client side" and "server side", which is a wholly different question.

Comment: @Scott Stafford : thanks for your comment. Just to clarify people: Front end : ascx
Back end: ascx.cs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please use `<%= GetPlantName(item) %>` instead of `<% GetPlantName(item) %>` and method should be Public or Protected.

Answer (score 8):

To return a string you need `Response.Write` which is written in shorthand as `<%=%>` so:

```
<%= GetPlantName(item) %>
```

Answer (score 3):

While your code might be working (with the fix suggested by others) it's not good practice. It's the classic ASP way while you're using ASP.NET - it's like driving 10 MPH with sport car on the highway.

One good practice can be to use the `Repeater` Control - it's still simple and it's much more elegant.

The `.aspx` will now look like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPlants" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><ol></HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></ol></FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <span class="folder">
                <%# Container.DataItem %>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And to bind the data have such code in the `Page_Load` function in your code behind:

```
string[] arrPlants = new string[] { "Sacred Datura", "Kambroo", "Wallflower", "Beech 'Retroflexa'", "Zephyr Flower" };
rptPlants.DataSource = arrPlants;
rptPlants.DataBind();
```

In your case just replace `arrPlants` with your real array, `Plants`.

Feel free to ask for further details or explanations. :)

Comment: I'm not sure if I agree that this is classic ASP. Although using the repeater control is good, this repeater control option is not avilable in MVC. Also, I have found that by creating your own controls, they usually work better and you don't get the restrictions posed by the controls.

Comment: @Funky I've written enough classic ASP believe me... having `Label` control and assigning its text in spaghetti code renders the usage of `Label` totally useless - the whole meaning of such control is that you can set its Text in the code behind. But I'm only one person and can't force my personal opinion on you - just give you my two cents and friendly advice. :)  Oh, and for the record - `<asp:Label>` is full scale server control as well. If you can use it, you probably can use Repeater as well.

Comment: Thats cool, I appreciate your feedback as I like to know if I'm doing the right thing! :) But what do you do if you don't have the repeater conrol available to use like in MVC? For this solution I will use the repeater like you mentioned as it's the best solution to a webforms site!

Comment: @Funky sorry, not familiar with MVC and you also didn't tag your question with that.. but I'm pretty sure they have better way than the dreaded spaghetti code? I surely saw too much of it during my days as classic ASP programmer. :)